# Access my ip wifi camera within OpenCV in ubuntu and wouldn't be connected/streaming

Tags: ip-camera, dronekit-python

I bought [Camera: Eachine E58 RC Quadcopter 0.3MP WIFI FPV](https://www.banggood.com/iw/Eachine-E58-RC-Quadcopter-Spare-Parts-0_3MP-WIFI-FPV-Camera-p-1228774.html?gmcCountry=IL&currency=ILS&createTmp=1&cur_warehouse=CN) and connected it to my smartphone, which works fine with an application called WIFI FPV.

I want is to connect my wifi camera to my ubuntu and stream the the video with openCV.  I searched for a driver, like wifi fpv camera in linux, but didn't find one.  There's just on android or windows(microsoft store).

Can anyone help me access my ip wifi camera in ubuntu/linux?

I used in my ubuntu openCV as a python code, it didn't work for me !
camera ip is : 192.168.0.1
port:80
protocol I guess it's DHCP 
I need a driver or something that I could stream my video from wifi camera to Ubuntu by wifi network of my camera, I used VLC player and it didn't work at all ! , I tried to search like wifi fpv app (as it works fine in my smartphone) but didn't find in ubuntu something like that .. so maybe anyone knows good driver for eachine camera in ubuntu? thanks alot !!

my goal at the end is to openCV video stream in my ubuntu(linux) and not to my smartphone(in smartphone it works fine with wifi fpv app but I need to stream it to my Linux)

I used `opencv` python code for getting stream of the video from the wifi camera, but it didn't work.  Although I already connected my laptop(linux) within the wifi camera.

Here's my code:

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.0.1:80/video')
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

In the user manual of couple of wifi cameras I bought an URL to access camera from computer, if both the camera and computer are connected to same wifi, was provided. Usually if we enter that URL in browser, username and password (can be found in the user manual) would be asked, entering which we will see the stream and other options(ex flip video, change password etc) on the browser.

To find the IP address, I paste the URL on to browser and try accessing it. If it opens up the video, it helps me determine that link is correct.

1. Enter the URL address to access camera (normally provided in the wifi camera manual) in browser with Developer Tools window enabled.
2. Developer Tools Network log will have an URL with the IP address of the camera. Find that IP address, it gets stream from camera and use it in the code.

In my windows computer I use this link:
cv2.VideoCapture('http://usrname:password@192.168.1.10:80/media/?action=stream')

Just giving a suggestion, if it helps..

Comment: I wonder what protocol is used in your setup for the video stream?

Comment: @matanster I am sorry, not sure if I got what you meant by protocol, but I used http/https at that time. I updated my original answer for clarity now.

Comment: There must be some sub-protocol used there, for streaming video I guess. [Might be this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming), or something else.